# Serve Distributed Vue Component from WebApi

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to be able to import and render a vue component from a asp.net core WebApi

I followed [this article](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/) to get an idea, and came up with the code below.

The endpoint does get hit, and returns the packaged component string as I expected, but I See these errors in the console:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost:44385/api/DistributedComponent/Test' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

and

> vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function () { return __awaiter(_this, void 0, void 0, function () { return __generator(this, function (_a) {
> switch (*a.label) {
> case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, Object(*js_util_external_component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3**["default"])('https://localhost:44385/api/DistributedComponent/Test')];
> case 1: return [2 /*return*/, _a.sent()];
> }
> }); }); }
> Reason: TypeError: Chaining cycle detected for promise #

I suspect I am not returning the component string correctly, but how should I return it? and How can I use these error messages to help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

**external-component.js**

```
export default async function externalComponent(url) {
    const name = 'MyComponent';

    if (window[name]) return window[name];

    window[name] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.async = true;
        script.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(window[name]);
        });
        script.addEventListener('error', () => {
            reject(new Error(`Error loading ${url}`));
        });
        script.src = url;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    });

    return window[name];
}
```

**controller endpoint:**

```
[HttpGet("Test")]
public string Test()
{
    // This is the output of the component after running
    // npx vue-cli-service build --target lib --formats umd-min --no-clean --dest server/components/MyComponent --name "MyComponent.[chunkhash]" server/components/MyComponent/MyComponent.vue
    return @"(function(e,t){""object""===typeof exports&&""object""===typeof module?module.exports=t():""function""===typeof define&&define.amd?define([],t):""object""===typeof exports?exports[""MyComponent.c9b7fae39bb9d71ad3e7""]=t():e[""MyComponent.c9b7fae39bb9d71ad3e7""]=t()})(""undefined""!==typeof self?self:this,(function(){return function(e){var t={};function n(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var o=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,n),o.l=!0,o.exports}return n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,r){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},n.r=function(e){""undefined""!==typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:""Module""}),Object.defineProperty(e,""__esModule"",{value:!0})},n.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=n(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&""object""===typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var r=Object.create(null);if(n.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,""default"",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&""string""!=typeof e)for(var o in e)n.d(r,o,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,o));return r},n.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e[""default""]}:function(){return e};return n.d(t,""a"",t),t},n.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},n.p="""",n(n.s=""fb15"")}({f6fd:function(e,t){(function(e){var t=""currentScript"",n=e.getElementsByTagName(""script"");t in e||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{get:function(){try{throw new Error}catch(r){var e,t=(/.*at [^\(]*\((.*):.+:.+\)$/gi.exec(r.stack)||[!1])[1];for(e in n)if(n[e].src==t||""interactive""==n[e].readyState)return n[e];return null}}})})(document)},fb15:function(e,t,n){""use strict"";var r;(n.r(t),""undefined""!==typeof window)&&(n(""f6fd""),(r=window.document.currentScript)&&(r=r.src.match(/(.+\/)[^/]+\.js(\?.*)?$/))&&(n.p=r[1]));var o=function(){var e=this,t=e.$createElement,n=e._self._c||t;return n(""h2"",[e._v(""Hello from the Distribution Server!"")])},i=[];function f(e,t,n,r,o,i,f,u){var c,a=""function""===typeof e?e.options:e;if(t&&(a.render=t,a.staticRenderFns=n,a._compiled=!0),r&&(a.functional=!0),i&&(a._scopeId=""data-v-""+i),f?(c=function(e){e=e||this.$vnode&&this.$vnode.ssrContext||this.parent&&this.parent.$vnode&&this.parent.$vnode.ssrContext,e||""undefined""===typeof __VUE_SSR_CONTEXT__||(e=__VUE_SSR_CONTEXT__),o&&o.call(this,e),e&&e._registeredComponents&&e._registeredComponents.add(f)},a._ssrRegister=c):o&&(c=u?function(){o.call(this,(a.functional?this.parent:this).$root.$options.shadowRoot)}:o),c)if(a.functional){a._injectStyles=c;var s=a.render;a.render=function(e,t){return c.call(t),s(e,t)}}else{var d=a.beforeCreate;a.beforeCreate=d?[].concat(d,c):[c]}return{exports:e,options:a}}var u={},c=f(u,o,i,!1,null,null,null),a=c.exports;t[""default""]=a}})[""default""]}));";
}
```

**Main Vue component:**

```
<template>
    <MyComponent />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Vue, Component, Mixins } from "vue-property-decorator";

    import externalComponent from '../../js/util/external-component';
    const MyComponent = () => externalComponent('https://localhost:44385/api/DistributedComponent/Test');

    @Component({
        name: "Dashboard",
        components: {
            MyComponent
        }
    })
    export default class Dashboard extends Vue {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to overcome these errors by updating my controller endpoint to:

```
[HttpGet("Test")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
    var bytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(@"Path\To\MyComponent.c9b7fae39bb9d71ad3e7.umd.min.js");

    return File(bytes, "application/javascript", "MyComponent.umd.min.js");
}
```

Which resolved the MIME type issue, and **external-component.js** to

```
export default async function externalComponent(url) {

    const name = 'MyComponent'; 

    if (window[name]) return window[name];

    window[name] = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.async = true;
        script.addEventListener('load', () => {
            console.log('load');
            resolve(window[name]);
        });
        script.addEventListener('error', () => {
            console.log('error');
            reject(new Error(`Error loading ${url}`));
        });
        script.src = url;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    });

    return window[name];
}
```

And this got rid of the async component error (we are now awaiting the component load Promise before returning `window[name]`

I do now get a

> TypeError: Cannot read property '__esModule' of undefined

for which I opened [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797719/dynamic-component-gives-typeerror-cannot-read-property-esmodule-of-undefine)